# Is this the (a?) correct definition for $X$ having full row rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ denote a $T\times K$ matrix. I have seen the definition for full column rank as "There is no vector $c \not = 0$ with $X\cdot c = 0$. Would a definition for full row rank then be "There does not exist a $b\not = 0$ such that $ b\cdot X = 0$?

Where I use $c$ for a $K\times 1$ vector and $b$ for a $ 1 \times T$ vector.

Thanks.

Comment: I've not seen these definitions before, but that would make sense. The first condition is equivalent to $\operatorname{rk} X = K$ and the second to $\operatorname{rk} X = T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $X$ denote a $T\times K$ matrix. I have seen the definition for full column rank as "There is no vector $c \not = 0$ with $X\cdot c = 0$. Would a definition for full row rank then be "There does not exist a $b\not = 0$ such that $ b\cdot X = 0$?

Yes: another definition (e.g. G. Strang. Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 4th end, p.478) of full column (row) rank is that the column (row) vectors are linearly independent. That definition is equivalent to the statements "$X\cdot \vec c = \vec 0$ iff $\vec c = \vec 0$" and "$\vec b\cdot X = \vec 0$ iff $\vec b = \vec 0$".